# Disable certain keys in jxbrowser

Tags: java, jxbrowser

I have a java based web application. I want to open the web application in kiosk mode so that the users using the application can not access any other applications on the computer e.g. any other browser, file explorer etc. Also, this web application has a login screen where user can enter their username and password. So , I need users be able to type in login details.

I am considering using jxbrowser for this. Here, in kiosk mode, How do I make sure that the users can not do `alt + tab` , `windows + d` etc.

Below is sample code.

```
 import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.InputEventsHandler;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.swing.BrowserView;

public class KioskApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create Browser instance
        final Browser browser = new Browser();
        BrowserView view = new BrowserView(browser);

        view.setKeyEventsHandler(new InputEventsHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            public boolean handle(KeyEvent event) {
                boolean b = event.isControlDown() 
                        || event.isAltDown() 
                        || event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_TAB 
                        || event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS;
                return b ;
            }
        });

        browser.loadURL("http://google.com");

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(view, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        // Remove window title and borders
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        // Make frame topmost
        frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        // Disable Alt+F4 on Windows
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        // Make frame full-screen
        frame.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        // Display frame
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

**Edit 1:**

ok. so I updated the code as shown above. Now, I can type in the jxbrowser. But I am still not able to prevent users from doing `alt + tab`  and `windows + d`

Answer (score 0):

The `alt + tab` and `windows + d` keys are system-level shortcuts that cannot be disabled using the JxBrowser API.

The `InputEventsHandler<KeyEvent>` is used to filter/suppress the keys and don't send them to the Chromium engine. If you disable `alt + tab` key for Chromium, it doesn't mean that the operating system won't get this key event and don't switch windows.

If you need to disable such keys, I recommend that you use one of the possible [approaches](https://www.google.com/search?q=disable%20alt%20tab&oq=disa&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i65j69i57j69i61l3.1418j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).